# Updating Progressbar in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

basically I'm trying to have my progress bar appear at different levels and colours, depending on the values returned, however my 2 progress bars always seem the same as each other, even though they're in different values. Moreover the colours don't update either.

```
 double DFuelLvl = client.GetTankAmounts("Diesel"); 
            double PFuelLvl =  client.GetTankAmounts("Unleaded");

            if (DFuelLvl < 300)
            {
                DieselBar.Value = 10;
                DieselBar.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                DieselBar.Style = System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
            }
            else if( DFuelLvl > 300 && DFuelLvl< 500)
            {
                DieselBar.Value = 35;
                DieselBar.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
                DieselBar.Style = System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
            }
            else if (DFuelLvl > 500 && DFuelLvl < 850)
           {
               DieselBar.Value = 75;
               DieselBar.ForeColor = Color.Green;
               DieselBar.Style = System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
           }
            else
            {
                DieselBar.Value = 100;
                DieselBar.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                DieselBar.Style = System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
            }

            if (PFuelLvl < 300)
            {
                Petrolbar.Value = 10;
                Petrolbar.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                Petrolbar.Style = System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
            }
            else if (PFuelLvl > 300 && DFuelLvl < 500)
            {
                Petrolbar.Value = 35;
                Petrolbar.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
            }
            else if (PFuelLvl > 500 && DFuelLvl < 850)
            {
                Petrolbar.Value = 75;
                Petrolbar.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                Petrolbar.Value = 100;
                Petrolbar.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
            }
```

Comment: `else if (PFuelLvl > 300 && DFuelLvl < 500)` ? Shouldn't it be `else if (PFuelLvl > 300 && PFuelLvl < 500)`?

Comment: Doh! Yeah thanks, but Still the colours don't change, very strange

Comment: can you try with updatelayout....PFuelLvl.Updatelayout()

Comment: The ForeColor property doesn't work if visual styles are enabled.

Comment: It works, thanks! But it looks pretty rubbish, haha

Comment: Is there a way to disable visual styles for just the progress bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling visual styles, and updating the Layout after the colour change  was sufficient.